# Distinguish between two emails using php

Tags: php

someone.12345678@something.in 
someone.12345@something.in

The **first** email ID contains **8 digits** before @ symbol, and the **second** email ID contains **5 digits** before @ symbol.

The first email ID belongs to group A and the second email ID belongs to group B.

How do we distinguish which group the submitted email ID belongs to using PHP code?

**Edit:** If the number of digits before @ is 8, the email ID belongs to the person of category A, and if it is 5 the email belongs to the person of category B.

Comment: What do you mean by `group`?

Comment: I think group means the number. For example there are two groups "12345678" and "12345" . Am i right?

Comment: @AdarshSojitra No. Maybe he has an Array or something with name A and similarly B. Question is unclear

Comment: What's the relation between those numbers & groups?

Comment: 5 digits means it belongs to the persons of category A; 8 digits means it belongs to the persons of category B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to distinguish the emails according to the groups. According to your question, `12345678` and `12345` are groups.
what you can do is explode the email two times. One time with `@` and second time with `.`. Let me show you how you can do this.

```
$email_exploded = explode('@',$email)    // this will give you ['someone.12345','something.in']
```

Now, You can further explode first part of the `$email_exploded` array with `.` and get the last part of the array. It will be your group. Just like this...

```
$email_array = explode('.',$email_exploded);
$group = end($email_array);
```

`$group` will be the group of each and every email. If you have an array of emails, you can run `foreach` loop and and make multi-dimensional array including email with its group. Let me know if it helps. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`strtok()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) to get the first part then parse the digits after the `.` and finally check the length.

```
$firstPart = strtok($email, '@');
$digits = substr($firstPart , strpos($firstPart, ".") + 1);
$len = strlen($digits);

if($len == 8){
    // group A
} else if($len == 5){
    // group B
}
```

Be sure to validate the email address first to ensure there's not multiple `@` symbols or other errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can split the email id at `@` with the help of explode, and can check the length of value at index 0, if length is 8 (or you may put your check) then it is group 1 and so on.